# Пьяного красноярца не пустили в храм(,) и он его поджег. Нужна запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

*Пьяного красноярца не пустили в храм(,) и он его поджег*. Нужна ли запятая перед "и"?

Answer (score 1):

Это ССП с союзом "и" меду двумя его частями, перед которым **положено ставить запятую**.

Постановка запятой перед союзом «и», соединяющим простые предложения в составе сложного.
Запятая СТАВИТСЯ, если соединяются простые предложения в составе сложносочинённого: [ ], и [ ].
Надвигалась гроза, и тучи заволокли всё небо.

Comment: но там ведь нет двух простых предложений....

Comment: *но там ведь нет двух простых предложений* - а что есть???

Comment: "Пьяного красноярца не пустили в храм." - предложение. "И он его поджёг." - предложение. Так что два простых предложения там есть.

Answer (score 1):

**Сложносочинённые предложения (ССП)** – это сложные предложения, в которых **простые предложения** связываются друг с другом **интонацией и сочинительными** **союзами.**
 В данном случае - ***соединительный союз " и ", перед которым ставится запятая:***
*Открыли дверь, и в кухню паром вкатился воздух со двора* (Паустовский).

Предложения, очень похожие на Ваше:

Инвалида ***не пустили*** в пансионат, ***и он замёрз*** на крыльце.
 «Лучшего друга» Трампа ***не пустили*** на инаугурацию, ***и он стал*** лишним на празднике жизни вместе с простыми американцами.
В Тюмени начальника отдела полиции ***не пустили*** без досмотра в ресторан, ***и* *он вызвал*** ОМОН.

Так что запятая перед "и" нужна.